# Gmail messages from myself aren't 'Important'

Tags: gmail

I send myself Emails sometimes, so I could search through my records easily.
Lately I noticed all emails from myself go straight to All Mail bypassing the Inbox and marked as unimportant.

I don't have any filters to do so!

How do I remove this behaviour? (important + in inbox).

Comment: Setup a filter that marks the email however you want.

Answer (score 5):

Create a filter for it, using your e-mail in `from:`  and checking `Always mark it as important` in the behavior.
That will put the e-mail right in the first inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Send yourself a test-email with some random text, using gmail.com in your browser.

Refresh the page and click the sent Email. Then click (in the menu) more and 'mark as important'.

And test it by sending yourself a Email. Right now your mail should appear in your mailbox.